# Filling area between curve and circle using TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf

The question is rather self-explaining. I have the picture below, and now I want to fill the two areas between the circle (arc) and the curves.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[thick,every node/.style={circle,scale=.5,fill}]

\draw (0,0) ++(160:3) arc (160:-160:3);

\node (e1) at (160:3) {};
\node (e2) at (-160:3) {};

\draw(e1) -- node[fill=none,left,scale=2] {$e$} (e2);

\draw plot [smooth] coordinates {(160:3) (130:2) (110:2.5) (100:2.5) (90:3)};
\draw plot [smooth] coordinates {(40:3) (30:1) (-40:1.5) (-80:3)};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can fill the area by drawing a closed path which is a combination of the curves and a corresponding arc.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[
    thick,
    every node/.style={
      circle,
      scale=.5,
      fill
    }
  ]
    \draw (0,0) ++(160:3) arc (160:-160:3);

    \node (e1) at (160:3) {};
    \node (e2) at (-160:3) {};

    \draw(e1) -- node[fill=none,left,scale=2] {$e$} (e2);

    \fill[cyan,draw=black] plot[smooth] coordinates {
      (160:3)
      (130:2)
      (110:2.5)
      (100:2.5)
      (90:3)
    } arc[radius=3,start angle=90,end angle=160];
    \fill[cyan,draw=black] plot[smooth] coordinates {
      (40:3)
      (30:1)
      (-40:1.5)
      (-80:3)
    } arc[radius=3,start angle=-80,end angle=40];
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The choice of the fill color is of course left to you. The chosen one here is only for demonstration purposes.

---

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Version 1.10 of pgfplots has been released just recently, and it comes with a new solution for the problem to fill the area between plots.

Note that the old solution is still possible and still valid; this here is merely an update which might simplify the task. In order to keep the knowledge base of this site up-to-date, I present a solution based on the new `fillbetween` library here:

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.10}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[thick,every node/.style={circle,scale=.5,fill}]

\draw[red,name path=arc]  (160:3) arc (160:-160:3);

\node (e1) at (160:3) {};
\node (e2) at (-160:3) {};

\draw(e1) -- node[fill=none,left,scale=2] {$e$} (e2);

\draw[name path=A] plot [smooth] coordinates {(140:3.01) (130:2) (110:2.5) (100:2.5) (90:3.01)};
\draw[name path=B] plot [smooth] coordinates {(40:3.001) (30:1) (-40:1.5) (-80:3.001)};

\tikzfillbetween[of=A and arc,on layer=,split,every even segment/.style={fill=none,draw=none}]{blue,opacity=50}


\tikzfillbetween[of=B and arc,on layer=,split,
    every even segment/.style={fill=none,draw=none},
]{red,opacity=50}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This solution relies on a `pgfplots` (!) solution, even though the plot as such is entirely unrelated to `pgfplots`. It makes use of `\tikzfillbetween` which comes with `\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}`.

The key idea is to draw the input paths entirely, and assign names to them. In our case, we have the `\draw` statement which is now labelled as `name path=arc`, and two plots which are named `A` and `B`, respectively. Then we have two `\tikzfillbetween` statements. These statements generate one or more `\draw` statements, depending on the options in square brackets. The options in square brackets determine which paths are input and some details like the styles and layers. The options in curly braces determine the common style. In our case, we use `fill=none,draw=none` for every even segment to show only the odd ones - try it out without the option. The option `on layer` with empty value means to use the current layer. Generally, `fillbetween` relies on layered graphics such that the input paths are drawn on top of the fill paths. In our case, we ignored it, but you may write `\pgfsetlayers{pre main,main}` after `\begin{tikzpicture}[..]` to enable layered graphics.