# How to fill area between two curves without fillbetween command

Tags: tikz-pgf

Is there any way to fill the area between the two curves I' ve made using tikz without addplot- fillbetween packages?

```
\usepackage{xltxtra}
\usepackage{xgreek}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amscd}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage[mathup=sym]{unicode-math}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pgf,tikz}
\usepackage{tkz-tab}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows,backgrounds}
\usetikzlibrary{scopes,svg.path,shapes.geometric,shadows}
\usepackage[left=1.5cm,right=1.5cm,top=2cm,bottom=1.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{kmath,kerkis}
\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text]{Kerkis}
\setmathfont[Scale=MatchUppercase]{STIX Two Math}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=5.6]
    \draw[very thick,dashed, opacity=0.7] (1,0)--(1,0.36784);
    \draw[very thick,dashed, opacity=0.7] (2,0)--(2,0.25);
    \draw[very thick, ->] (-0.5,0) -- (2.3,0)node[pos=1,below]{$x$};
    \draw[very thick, ->] (0,-0.5) -- (0,0.85)node[pos=1,left]{$y$};
     \foreach \x in {1,...,2}\draw[shift={(\x,0)},color=black]
(0pt,0.8pt) -- (0pt,-0.8pt);
\foreach \i in {1,2}
\draw[shift={(\i,0)},color=black](0pt,0pt) -- (0pt,-0.8pt)node[below]{$\i$};
\node[below right](o) at (0,0){$0$};
    \draw[ultra thick, samples=100, draw=red, domain=-0.35:2] plot (\x,{\x*e^(-\x)});
     \draw[ultra thick, samples=100, draw=ballblue!60!black, domain=-0:1] plot (\x,{sqrt(\x)*e^(-sqrt(\x))});
\node[circle, draw=black, inner sep=1.7pt, fill=white](a) at (2,0.27){};
\node[circle, draw=black, inner sep=1.4pt,fill=black!50!white](a) at (1,0.36787){};
\node[circle, draw=black, inner sep=1.4pt,fill=black!50!white](a) at (0,0){};
 \node[red]() at (1.7,0.4){\begin{LARGE}
$C_{\,f}$
\end{LARGE}};
 \node[ballblue!60!black,below]() at (0.12,0.45){\begin{LARGE}
$C_{\,g}$
\end{LARGE}};
    \end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. When you post a question, please provide a ["Minimal Working Example" (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that starts with `\documentclass`, includes all relevant `\usepackage` commands, ends with `\end{document}` and compiles without errors, even if it does not produce your desired output.

Comment: Just repeat both curves in a single \fill, except one right to left and the other left to right.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

After cleaning A LOT of your code, I have added SOME lines of mine to have a working program that answer your question:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[left=1.5cm,right=1.5cm,top=2cm,bottom=1.5cm]{geometry}

\begin{document}
    \thispagestyle{empty}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=4]
    \draw[very thick,dashed, opacity=0.7] (1,0)--(1,0.36784);
    \draw[very thick,dashed, opacity=0.7] (2,0)--(2,0.25);
    \draw[very thick, ->] (-0.5,0) -- (2.3,0)node[pos=1,below]{$x$};
    \draw[very thick, ->] (0,-0.5) -- (0,0.85)node[pos=1,left]{$y$};
    \foreach \x in {1,...,2}\draw[shift={(\x,0)},color=black]
    (0pt,0.8pt) -- (0pt,-0.8pt);
    \foreach \i in {1,2}
    \draw[shift={(\i,0)},color=black](0pt,0pt) -- (0pt,-0.8pt)node[below]{$\i$};
    \node[below right](o) at (0,0){$0$};
    \draw[ultra thick, samples=100, draw=red, domain=-0.35:2] plot (\x,{\x*e^(-\x)});
    \draw[ultra thick, samples=100, draw=blue!60!black, domain=-0:1] plot (\x,{sqrt(\x)*e^(-sqrt(\x))});
    \node[circle, draw=black, inner sep=1.7pt, fill=white](a) at (2,0.27){};
    \node[circle, draw=black, inner sep=1.4pt,fill=black!50!white](a) at (1,0.36787){};
    \node[circle, draw=black, inner sep=1.4pt,fill=black!50!white](a) at (0,0){};
    \node[red] at (1.7,0.4) () {$C_{f}$};
    \node[blue!60!black,below] at (0.12,0.45) () {$C_{g}$};
    \foreach \x in {0.000,0.001,...,1.000}                          % <--- added
    \draw[cyan] (\x,{\x*e^(-\x)})--(\x,{sqrt(\x)*e^(-sqrt(\x))});   % <--- added
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

**ADD**: The result is better if you put the 'fill' code before the 'graphing' code:

```
\foreach \x in {0.000,0.001,...,1.000}                          % <--- added
\draw[cyan] (\x,{\x*e^(-\x)})--(\x,{sqrt(\x)*e^(-sqrt(\x))});   % <--- added
\draw[ultra thick, samples=100, draw=red, domain=-0.35:2] plot (\x,{\x*e^(-\x)});
\draw[ultra thick, samples=100, draw=blue!60!black, domain=-0:1] plot (\x,{sqrt(\x)*e^(-sqrt(\x))});
\node[circle, draw=black, inner sep=1.7pt, fill=white](a) at (2,0.27){};
\node[circle, draw=black, inner sep=1.4pt,fill=black!50!white](a) at (1,0.36787){};
\node[circle, draw=black, inner sep=1.4pt,fill=black!50!white](a) at (0,0){};
\node[red] at (1.7,0.4) () {$C_{f}$};
\node[blue!60!black,below] at (0.12,0.45) () {$C_{g}$};
```

In this case the output is:

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Mostly off topic, but can be helpful :-)

- I would put a little bit of effort to define image elements style which enable to write much shorter code for diagram:
- For filling use @John Kormylo comment, where I would for blue curve define domain as `samples at={0,0.01,...,0.2,0.3,...,1}`.
- Diagram looks nicer (to my opinion), if the `fill` is drawn first, than curves.
- MWE (Minimal Working Example) is:

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\begin{document}
    \thispagestyle{empty}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=4,
arr/.style = {-Straight Barb},
wdt/.style = {circle, draw, solid, fill=white, inner sep=2pt},
tck/.style = {rounded corners, inner sep=2pt, fill=white, anchor=north}
                    ]
% axis
\draw[arr] (-0.5,0) -- (2.3,0) node[below left]    {$x$};
\draw[arr] (0,-0.5) -- (0,0.8) node[below left]    {$y$};
% fill between curves
\fill[cyan] plot[samples at={0,0.01,...,0.2,0.3,...,1}] (\x,{sqrt(\x)*e^(-sqrt(\x))}) --
            plot[samples=100, domain=1:0] (\x,{\x*e^(-\x)});
% curves
\draw[ultra thick, samples=100, red] plot[domain=-0.35:2] (\x,{\x*e^(-\x)});
\draw[ultra thick, samples=100, blue!60!black]  plot[domain=-0:1] (\x,{sqrt(\x)*e^(-sqrt(\x))});
% circles + dashed line
    \foreach \x in {0,1,2}
\draw[dashed]  (\x,{\x*e^(-\x)})  node (\x) [wdt] {} -- (\x |- 0,-1pt) node[tck] {\x};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

With the comment of John Kormylo and the post [Filling area between curve and circle using TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/147522/filling-area-between-curve-and-circle-using-tikz/163657#163657)
I tried:

```
\fill[cyan,draw=black] plot[smooth, domain=0:1] (\x,{\x*e^(-\x)}) plot [smooth, domain=1:0](\x,{sqrt(\x)*e^(-sqrt(\x))});
```

[image]

To eliminate the parasitic line, I tried `samples=2000`
[image]

```
\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    %  initial answer
    % \fill[cyan,draw=black] plot[smooth, samples=2000,domain=0:1] (\x,{\x*e^(-\x)}) plot [smooth, samples=2000, domain=1:0](\x,{sqrt(\x)*e^(-sqrt(\x))});
    % 
    %   EDIT2
    %
    \fill[cyan,draw=black] plot[domain=0:1] (\x,{\x*e^(-\x)}) -- plot [ domain=1:0](\x,{sqrt(\x)*e^(-sqrt(\x))})--cycle;
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

EDIT2: By being more attentive to Jasper Habicht's comment, the problem does not come from the number of `samples` but from the link between the curves `--` and `--cycle`

EDIT3: With the second comment of Jasper Habicht, I finally understood everything (Uh, I think).

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\section{Without \texttt{--} between the two curves}
\subsection{Without $samples=2^n+1$}
\begin{itemize}
  \item $samples=25$ (by default)
  \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2]
    \fill[cyan,draw=black] plot[domain=0:1] (\x,{\x*e^(-\x)})  plot [ domain=1:0](\x,{sqrt(\x)*e^(-sqrt(\x))});
  \end{tikzpicture}
  \item $samples=258$
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2]
    \fill[cyan,draw=black] plot[samples=258,domain=0:1] (\x,{\x*e^(-\x)})  plot [ samples=258,domain=1:0](\x,{sqrt(\x)*e^(-sqrt(\x))});
  \end{tikzpicture}
  \item $samples=2000$
  \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2]
      \fill[cyan,draw=black] plot[samples=2000,domain=0:1] (\x,{\x*e^(-\x)})  plot [ samples=2000,domain=1:0](\x,{sqrt(\x)*e^(-sqrt(\x))});
    \end{tikzpicture}
    It seems to work, but the reasoning is not good.
\end{itemize}
\subsection{With $samples=2^n+1$}
\begin{itemize}
  \item $samples=33$
  \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2]
      \fill[cyan,draw=black] plot[samples=33,domain=0:1] (\x,{\x*e^(-\x)})  plot [ samples=33,domain=1:0](\x,{sqrt(\x)*e^(-sqrt(\x))});
    \end{tikzpicture}
  \item $samples=129$
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2]
    \fill[cyan,draw=black] plot[samples=129,domain=0:1] (\x,{\x*e^(-\x)})  plot [ samples=129,domain=1:0](\x,{sqrt(\x)*e^(-sqrt(\x))});
  \end{tikzpicture}
  \item $samples=257$
  \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2]
      \fill[cyan,draw=black] plot[samples=257,domain=0:1] (\x,{\x*e^(-\x)})  plot [ samples=257,domain=1:0](\x,{sqrt(\x)*e^(-sqrt(\x))});
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{itemize}
\section{With \texttt{--} and \texttt{-cycle}, it always works}
\begin{itemize}
  \item $samples=25$ (by default)
  \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2]
    \fill[cyan,draw=black] plot[domain=0:1] (\x,{\x*e^(-\x)}) -- plot [ domain=1:0](\x,{sqrt(\x)*e^(-sqrt(\x))})--cycle;
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{itemize}
\begin{itemize}
  \item $samples=258$ (by default)
  \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2]
    \fill[cyan,draw=black] plot[samples=258,domain=0:1] (\x,{\x*e^(-\x)}) -- plot [ samples=258,domain=1:0](\x,{sqrt(\x)*e^(-sqrt(\x))})--cycle;
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{itemize}
\section{What I remember}
\begin{itemize}
  \item Read comments carefully (A big thank you to Jasper Habicht)
  \item Do not forget \texttt{--} and \texttt{-cycle}
  \item Why not take $samples=2^n+1$
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\fill[cyan, draw=black] plot[smooth, samples=257, domain=0:1] (\x,{\x*e^(-\x)}) -- plot[smooth, samples=257, domain=1:0] (\x,{sqrt(\x)*e^(-sqrt(\x))}) -- cycle;` should be sufficient. It is advisable to use a value for `samples` that satisfies 2ⁿ + 1.

Comment: @Jasper Habicht, I had made a first test with 1000 and I naively thought that this number should be increased. I also notice that with 256 and 258, we still have the problem.

Comment: @Jasper Hanicht, sorry, I didn't pay enough attention to your comment, I hadn't seen the -- and the --cycle. Thanks, now I understand.

Comment: The settings `plot [smooth, samples=200, domain=1:0]` give a better result.

Comment: @projetmbc Yes, but what I didn't understand was the spurious line that didn't appear with 257 points but with 258 (without the -- and --cycle)

Comment: It is not so much a problem of how large the number is. Although the path will be smoother with more `samples`, even very large numbers may result in suboptimal output, because of imprecisions during calculation. Essentially, the path will be split up into the x - 1 parts if you set `samples` to a value of x and for each of these parts the coordinates are calculated. Now, TeX is not too good at dividing numbers, but it is okay with calculating powers of two (this is what computers are good at in general). Therefore, a number that satisfies 2ⁿ + 1 is often a good choice for the `samples` value.

Comment: @Jasper Habicht, I finally understood everything (Uh, I think). Thanks very much

Answer (score 2):

Purely for comparison, here is a version using [Metapost](https://tug.org/metapost.html).

[image]

This is wrapped up in `luamplib` so you need to compile it with `lualatex`.  I've included some notes in the comments.

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{luamplib}
\begin{document}
\mplibtextextlabel{enable}
\begin{mplibcode}
beginfig(1);
    numeric u; u = 144;  % define a unit for scaling
    path xx, yy; % define the axes
    xx = (left -- 5 right) scaled 1/2 u; 
    yy = (down -- up) scaled 1/2 u;
    % define the two curves
    path ff, gg;
    % in MP mexp(256x) is the same as exp(x) in the rest of the world
    vardef f(expr x) = x * mexp(-256 x) enddef;
    vardef g(expr x) = sqrt(x) * mexp(-256 sqrt(x)) enddef;
    numeric s; s = 1/8;
    ff = (for x = -3/8 step s until 2-s: (x, f(x)) .. endfor (2, f(2))) scaled u;
    gg = (for x =    0 step s until 1-s: (x, g(x)) .. endfor (1, g(1))) scaled u;

    % since we have set s=1/8, path ff will have 19 points, hence
    % subpath (3, 11) gives us the segment between 0 and 1
    % which can be spliced to gg running backwards and closed with cycle
    fill subpath (3, 11) of ff & reverse gg & cycle withcolor 7/8[blue, white];

    % draw and label the curves in colour
    drawoptions(withcolor 2/3 blue);
    draw gg; label.ulft("$C_g$", point 2 of gg);
    drawoptions(withcolor 3/4 red);
    draw ff; label.urt("$C_f$", point 17 of ff);
    drawoptions();

    % draw the axes, with slim arrows, and labels
    interim ahangle := 30;
    drawarrow xx; label.rt("$x$", point 1 of xx);
    drawarrow yy; label.top("$y$", point 1 of yy);

    % add fancy labels at 0, 1, and 2.
    forsuffixes $ = 0, 1, 2: 
        z$ = ($, f($)) scaled u;
        if $ > 0:
            draw (x$,0) -- z$ dashed evenly scaled 1/2; 
            label.bot("$" & str $ & "$", (x$, 0));
        else:
            label.lrt("$" & str $ & "$", origin);
        fi
        draw z$ withpen pencircle scaled dotlabeldiam;
        draw z$ withpen pencircle scaled 3/4 dotlabeldiam withcolor white;
    endfor
endfig;
\end{mplibcode}
\end{document}
```

Comment: So cute! Really.