# Not a good result for a graph made with tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphs

I made the graph of `y = \sqrt{|x|}` with TikZ and the result isn't so good close to the beginning of the axes. Below you can see the difference between a photo from GeoGebra and [this TeXlive.net snippet](https://texlive.net/run?%5Cdocumentclass%5Ba4paper,10pt%5D%7Barticle%7D%0A%5Cusepackage%7Bpgf,tikz%7D%0A%0A%5Cbegin%7Bdocument%7D%0A%5Cbegin%7Btikzpicture%7D%5Bscale=2%5D%0A%20%20%20%20%5Cdraw%5Bvery%20thick,%20-%3E%5D%20(-2.5,0)%20--%20(2.5,0)node%5Bpos=1,above%5D%7B$x$%7D;%0A%20%20%20%20%5Cdraw%5Bvery%20thick,%20-%3E%5D%20(0,-1.2)%20--%20(0,3)node%5Bpos=1,left%5D%7B$y$%7D;%0A%20%20%20%20%20%5Cforeach%20%5Cx%20in%20%7B-2,...,2%7D%5Cdraw%5Bshift=%7B(%5Cx,0)%7D,color=black%5D%0A(0pt,0.8pt)%20--%20(0pt,-0.8pt);%0A%5Cforeach%20%5Ci%20in%20%7B1,2%7D%0A%5Cdraw%5Bshift=%7B(%5Ci,0)%7D,color=black%5D(0pt,0pt)%20--%20(0pt,-0.8pt)node%5Bbelow%5D%7B$%5Ci$%7D;%0A%5Cforeach%20%5Ci%20in%20%7B-2,-1%7D%0A%5Cdraw%5Bshift=%7B(%5Ci,0)%7D,color=black%5D(0pt,0pt)%20--%20(0pt,-0.8pt)node%5Bbelow%5D%7B$%5Ci$%7D;%0A%5Cnode%5Bbelow%20right%5D(o)%20at%20(0,0)%7B$0$%7D;%0A%20%20%20%20%20%5Cdraw%5Bultra%20thick,%20samples=100,%20draw=black,%20domain=-2.5:2.5%5D%20plot%20(%5Cx,%7Bsqrt(abs(%5Cx))%7D);%0A%20%20%20%20%5Cend%7Btikzpicture%7D%0A%5Cend%7Bdocument%7D).

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage{pgf,tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2]
    \draw[very thick, ->] (-2.5,0) -- (2.5,0)node[pos=1,above]{$x$};
    \draw[very thick, ->] (0,-1.2) -- (0,3)node[pos=1,left]{$y$};
     \foreach \x in {-2,...,2}\draw[shift={(\x,0)},color=black]
(0pt,0.8pt) -- (0pt,-0.8pt);
\foreach \i in {1,2}
\draw[shift={(\i,0)},color=black](0pt,0pt) -- (0pt,-0.8pt)node[below]{$\i$};
\foreach \i in {-2,-1}
\draw[shift={(\i,0)},color=black](0pt,0pt) -- (0pt,-0.8pt)node[below]{$\i$};
\node[below right](o) at (0,0){$0$};
     \draw[ultra thick, samples=100, draw=black, domain=-2.5:2.5] plot (\x,{sqrt(abs(\x))});
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: geogebra graph]

Comment: "Below you can see the difference" -- WDYM? There's only one image.

Comment: @DanMašek Take a look at the snippet...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This interesting post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/672163/6880) explains how to use efficiently `sample`. This gives the following easy solution.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage{pgf,tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2]
    \draw[very thick, ->] (-2.5,0) -- (2.5,0)node[pos=1,above]{$x$};
    \draw[very thick, ->] (0,-1.2) -- (0,3)node[pos=1,left]{$y$};
     \foreach \x in {-2,...,2}\draw[shift={(\x,0)},color=black]
(0pt,0.8pt) -- (0pt,-0.8pt);
\foreach \i in {1,2}
\draw[shift={(\i,0)},color=black](0pt,0pt) -- (0pt,-0.8pt)node[below]{$\i$};
\foreach \i in {-2,-1}
\draw[shift={(\i,0)},color=black](0pt,0pt) -- (0pt,-0.8pt)node[below]{$\i$};
\node[below right](o) at (0,0){$0$};
     % Use 2^n + 1 for sample.
     % line join=bevel  <--  See the quark67's comment.
     \draw[ultra thick, samples=257, draw=black, domain=-2.5:2.5, line join=bevel] plot (\x,{sqrt(abs(\x))});
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: If you look carefully with a magnify glass, and with a non black drawing (eg, red), you will see the drawing is a little below the x axis. You can avoid this by adding `line join=bevel` in the options of the `\draw` command.

Answer (score 5):

I would suggest to use `pgfplots` for the graph. It is much easier.

```
\documentclass[x11names,svgnames,11pt]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis} [ width=12cm,
  xlabel = $x$, ylabel = $y$,                                                           
  ]                                                                     
                                                                        
  \addplot [red,thick,domain=-3:3,samples=500,smooth]                   
    {sqrt(abs(x))} ;                                                    

\end{axis}  
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

The output:

[image]

Comment: Great. Replace the number of samples to an odd number like 501. So you will plot the point (0,0). With an even number of sample, you don't reach the value x=0, and in the graph, at minimum you obtain y ≈ 0.07 (if you plot 4 points evenly spaced between -3 and 3, you will plot at x=-3, x=-1, x=1 and x=3, but not at x=0).

Comment: @mas Sometimes, we only work with GeoGebra...

Comment: I understand. I just wanted to suggest that `pgfplots` was easier than plain `tikz` as your question mentions that you wanted to draw a graph.