# How to plot absolute value function?

Tags: tikz-pgf, amsmath, physics

To preface this, I just started learning LaTeX today as my professor wants us to complete homework assignments in it from now on. I've attached all my code, but the problem area is the very bottom. I'm trying to plot the absolute value of `\phi (t) - \phi_n (t)` (only done the first one so far), but as far as I can tell, there's no common package that has a built in absolute value function that actually does math instead of just formatting the bars. Is there some functionality or package I've missed?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{fullpage,mathpazo,amsfonts,nicefrac,amsmath,amssymb,enumitem, geometry, pgfplots, physics}
\pgfplotsset{compat = newest}
\geometry{top = 20mm, bottom = 20mm, left = 20mm, right = 20mm}

\begin{document}
\section*{2.8}
\begin{enumerate}[start = 2]
  \item Transform the given initial value problem
into an equivalent problem with the initial point at the origin.
    \begin{gather*}
      \frac{dy}{dt} = 1 - y^3, \quad \quad y(-1) = 3 \\
      T = t + 1 \Longrightarrow y(0) = 0 \\
      \frac{dy}{dt} = \frac{dy}{dT} * \frac{dT}{dt} = \frac{dy}{dT} \\
      \frac{dy}{dT} = 1 - y^3 \\
      Y = y-3 \\
      \frac{dy}{dT} = 1 - (Y + 3)^3 \\
      \frac{dY}{dT} = 1 - (Y + 3)^3, \quad \quad Y(0) = 0 \\
    \end{gather*}
\end{enumerate}
    \begin{enumerate}[start = 4]
      \item Let $\phi _0 (t) = 0$ and define $\{\phi _n (t)\}$ by the method of successive approximations. 
      \[
      y' = -\frac{y}{2} + t, \quad \quad y(0) = 0
      \]
        \begin{enumerate}
            \item Determine $\phi _n (t)$ for an arbitrary value of n.
            \begin{gather*}
                \int_{0}^{t} \,dy = \int_{0}^{t} -\frac{y}{2} + s \,ds \\ 
                \begin{align*}
                     \phi (t) &= \int_{0}^{t} -\frac{y}{2} + s \,ds \Longrightarrow \phi_{n+1} (t) = \int_{0}^{t} -\frac{\phi_n}{2} + s \,ds \\ 
                    \phi_1 (t) &= \int_{0}^{t} -\frac{y_0}{2} + s \,ds = \frac{t^2}{2} \\
                    \phi_2 (t) &= \int_{0}^{t} -\frac{s^2}{4} + s \,ds = -\frac{t^3}{12} + \frac{t^2}{2}\\
                    \phi_3 (t) &= \int_{0}^{t} -\frac{s^3}{24} + \frac{s^2}{4} + s \,ds = \frac{t^4}{96} - \frac{t^3}{12} + \frac{t^2}{2}\\
                    \phi_4 (t) &= \int_{0}^{t} \frac{s^4}{192} -\frac{s^3}{24} + \frac{s^2}{4} + s \,ds = -\frac{t^5}{960} + \frac{t^4}{96} - \frac{t^3}{12} + \frac{t^2}{2}
                \end{align*} \\
                \phi_n (t) = 4 \sum_{i=0}^{n} \frac{ (-\frac{t}{2})^i }{ i! } + 2t -4 \\
            \end{gather*}
            \item Plot $\phi_n (t)$ for $n = 1\ldots4$. Observe whether the iterates appear to be converging.
                \begin{tikzpicture}
                    \begin{axis}[
                        grid = both,
                        width = .75 * \textwidth,
                        height = .5 * \textwidth,
                        legend pos = north west,
                        xlabel = t, ylabel = $\phi_n (t)$,
                        xmin = 0, xmax = 10,
                        ymin = 0, ymax = 20]
                    \addplot[domain = 0:10, samples = 100, smooth, thick, blue,] {(x^2)/2};
                    \addplot[domain = 0:10, samples = 100, smooth, thick, red,] {-x^3/12 + (x^2)/2};
                    \addplot[domain = 0:10, samples = 100, smooth, thick, green,] {x^4/96 -x^3/12 + (x^2)/2};
                    \addplot[domain = 0:10, samples = 100, smooth, thick, pink,] {-x^5/960 + x^4/96 -x^3/12 + (x^2)/2};
                    \addplot[domain = 0:10, samples = 200, smooth, thick, black,] {4*exp(-x/2) + 2*x - 4};

                    \legend{$\phi_1 (t)$, $\phi_2 (t)$, $\phi_3 (t)$, $\phi_4 (t)$, $\phi (t)$}
                    \end{axis}
                \end{tikzpicture} 
                \\ The iterates do appear to be converging as $n$ increases.
            
            \item Express $\lim_{n\to\infty} \phi_n (t) = \phi (t)$ in terms of elementary functions; that is, solve the given initial value problem.
                \begin{align*}
                    \lim_{n\to\infty} \phi_n (t) &= \lim_{n\to\infty} 4 \sum_{i=0}^{n} \frac{ (-\frac{t}{2})^i }{ i! } + 2t -4\\
                    &= 4e^{-\frac{t}{2}} + 2t -4 \\
                    \phi_n (t) &= 4e^{-\frac{t}{2}} + 2t -4 
                \end{align*}
                \[ \phi (t) =  4e^{-\frac{t}{2}} + 2t -4 , \quad \quad \phi (0) = y (0) = 0 \]
            \item Plot $|\phi (t) - \phi_n (t)|$ for each value of $n$. Estimate the interval in which each is a reasonably good approximation to the actual solution. \\
                \begin{tikzpicture}
                    \begin{axis}[
                        grid = both,
                        width = .75 * \textwidth,
                        height = .5 * \textwidth,
                        legend pos = north west,
                        xlabel = t, ylabel = $\phi_n (t)$,
                        xmin = 0, xmax = 10,
                        ymin = 0, ymax = 10]
                    \addplot[domain = 0:10, samples = 100, smooth, thick, blue,] {{4*exp(-x/2) + 2*x - 4 - (x^2)/2}};
                    \addplot[domain = 0:10, samples = 100, smooth, thick, red,] {-x^3/12 + (x^2)/2};
                    \addplot[domain = 0:10, samples = 100, smooth, thick, green,] {x^4/96 -x^3/12 + (x^2)/2};
                    \addplot[domain = 0:10, samples = 100, smooth, thick, pink,] {-x^5/960 + x^4/96 -x^3/12 + (x^2)/2};
                    \addplot[domain = 0:10, samples = 200, smooth, thick, black,] {4*exp(-x/2) + 2*x - 4};

                    \legend{$\phi_1 (t)$, $\phi_2 (t)$, $\phi_3 (t)$, $\phi_4 (t)$, $\phi (t)$}
                    \end{axis}
                \end{tikzpicture}

        \end{enumerate}
    \end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Is [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/673683/not-a-good-result-for-a-graph-made-with-tikz) solves your problem?

Comment: Have you tried `abs(...)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you mean?

[image]

```
\addplot[domain = 0:10, samples = 100, smooth, thick, blue,] {{abs((4*exp(-x/2) + 2*x - 4)-(4*exp(-x/2) + 2*x - 4 - (x^2)/2))}};
\addplot[domain = 0:10, samples = 100, smooth, thick, red,] {abs((4*exp(-x/2) + 2*x - 4)-(-x^3/12 + (x^2)/2))};
\addplot[domain = 0:10, samples = 100, smooth, thick, green,] {abs((4*exp(-x/2) + 2*x - 4)-(x^4/96 -x^3/12 + (x^2)/2))};
\addplot[domain = 0:10, samples = 100, smooth, thick, pink,] {abs((4*exp(-x/2) + 2*x - 4)-(x^5/960 + x^4/96 -x^3/12 + (x^2)/2))};
\addplot[domain = 0:10, samples = 200, smooth, thick, black,] {4*exp(-x/2) + 2*x - 4};

\legend{$|\phi (t)-\phi_1 (t)|$, $|\phi (t)-\phi_2 (t)|$, $|\phi (t)-\phi_3 (t)|$, $|\phi (t)-\phi_4 (t)|$, $\phi (t)$}
```

Comment: yup, i messed up the formatting for abs(). thank you!